# can not add new classifier to weka although I don't have any error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weka

I have imported weka source code as a maven project into eclipse without any error but when I want to run `GUIchooser.java` I get this text in console as below:

```
 May 12, 2018 1:50:18 PM com.github.fommil.jni.JniLoader liberalLoad

INFO: successfully loaded /tmp/jniloader3338685618862893341netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64.so

May 12, 2018 1:50:18 PM com.github.fommil.jni.JniLoader liberalLoad

INFO: successfully loaded /tmp/jniloader3338685618862893341netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64.so
```

The `weka-GUI run`; but my own `classifier` which I had added to weka before running `GUIchooser.java`, is not added to `GUI classifiers`.

I use `ubuntu 16.4` but I have same problem in `windows 10`.
I also use `weka 3.8.1`

Comment: I don’t see a warning.

Comment: I'm not sure! I see this (red color)text in console, so I used warning! but I have _warnings_ and _infos_  too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just copied another classifier source code to 'myClassifier.java'. finally I could see my package and classifier in the weka GUI.

now I can modify the previous classifier code.